# request module doesn't callback after browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm trying to use the 'request' npm module in a client side lib with browserify but I'm having trouble.

The code I have is pretty standard, I'm posting a request to the server from the browserified version with something like:

```
request.post("/comments", { json: self }, function(err, resp, body) {
  // ... handle response here ...
});
```

but I'm not getting called back from request even though I see that the request is successful in the network tab of Chrome.   Has anyone seen this before?   Do I need to substitute a client version of 'request' for the node.js one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` has quite a few dependencies, and when I try and browserify it, I get a version of  the following:

```
Error: module "dns" not found from "node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/sntp/lib/index.js"
```

I'd suggest one of the following:

- [browser-request](https://github.com/iriscouch/browser-request) - port of `request` for the browser.
- [hyperquest](https://github.com/substack/hyperquest) - streaming http requests.  Not the full api that `request` provides, but it's lighter weight.  It won't parse response bodies for you though, which I'm guessing you want.